# FormatException was unhandled: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, multiplication

I can't multiply the value of the two textboxes.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
    {
        textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
    {
        textBox5.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text)).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that they containt **integer** values? If not how do you expres decimal seperator. Also are you aware that your code catches empty string ("") but not whitespaces (" ")?

Comment: `parse` / `tryparse` might be a better solution.

Comment: Make sure the text box values contain valid integers. Also, watch out for spaces. Use `Trim()` just in case, like textBox1.Text.Trim().

Comment: Hey guys, I got a correction on my question. The program actually works when I try to add those 2 textboxes. The problem is I want to find the sum of the textbox1 which has a value of an integer and textbox2 which has a value of a float number(decimal point). How will I able to find the sum of those 2 different datatypes? Thanks for the help guys,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to point you in the right direction...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float tbox1 = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        float tbox2 = float.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        float tbox12;

        if (textBox1 != null && textBox2 != null)
        {
            tbox12 = tbox1 + tbox2;
            textBox3.Text = tbox12.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {
        float tbox3 = float.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        float tbox4 = float.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        float tbox34;

        if (textBox3 != null && textBox4 != null)
        {
           tbox34 =  tbox3 + tbox4;
           textBox5.Text = tbox34.ToString();
        }       

    }
```

Comment: The first method(button1_Click) which checks the value of the textboxes 1 & 2 works. But when I use the same process on the second method(button2_Click), it didn't work(multiply). Then this thing pops up: "FormatException was unhandled: Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: @bigbryan In your button2_click method you show a `+` instead of `*` See my updated answer with button 2 included.

Comment: I got a wrong description on my program. I got a correction on my question. The program actually works when I try to add those 2 textboxes. The problem is I want to find the sum of the textbox1 which has a value of an integer and textbox2 which has a value of a float number(decimal point). How will I able to find the sum of those 2 different datatypes? 

I tried to run your code and it works if you want to multiply 2 integers. But I just realized that I was actually multiplying an integer to a float number, that is why the program has an error.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change `int` to `float`; revised answer. Make sure you ask your questions clearly!

Comment: In `button2_Click`, you use `textBox3.Text` **then** check if it's `null`. If it was null, you'd get a `NullReferenceException`. If it's not null, then `textBox3 != null` will always return true...

Comment: Thanks you so much. I really appreciate your help. 
Problem solved. 

Thanks for the advise. I'll keep it in mind next time.